# Integrate PCLint to VC++ for possible suggestion and solution

Tags: c++, visual-c++, search-engine, static-analysis, search-suggestion

The trigger for this idea is from `purify`. When we use purify, it has a extensive online help (`online` here means option in command prompt) which will help developer to understand the error and possible fixes.

Similar to this, I would like to have PCLint integrated to VC++ (one of the customized command in VC++) where for each error I would be able to get possible suggestion and solution. I have the PCLint already set-up and running with VC++, now is there any tool in the open to "link" these error and warnings so that it helps all developers in the team to learn and fix them?

Ideally a plugin, with all possible suggestion and solution to each warning/error/info to PCLint would do, but I am not able to find them. So asking for your help.